# Problema de licensia en Unity hub 3.0.1

Tags: unity

Al conectar mi cuenta de Unity a Unity Hub 3.0.1, no detecta la licencia personal que ya tengo, y cuando intento obtener otra cuenta personal en Unity Hub, aparece el error "There was a problem activating a new personal license. Make sure you are logged in, and have internet connection"

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con **Preference/Advance** y en **Channels** pon en modo **BETA**.

Se tiene que poner el **Unity Hub 3.1.0 beta.1** y prueba activando la licencia.